# Conversion to complete Bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Does anybody know how to convert an image or arbitrary graph to a graph, which would satisfy following criteria:

- must be bipartite.
- eigenvalues of its adjacency matrix must be in the set {0,d} for some real value d

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you’d like the transform to do? For example, we could meet the current requirements by outputting a fixed bipartite graph regardless of the input graph (or input image).

Comment: I want to test a novel algorithm for graph similarity, but the input graphs must meet those two criterias, thus was wondering, if there is a way to convert images of other arbitrary graphs in to that form?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to just generate random bipartite graphs with these properties? Any reason for converting existing objects into bipartite graphs?